Is it possible to change the url in view (Django) after a certain operation?
Let's say there is a page of a separate blog article with this url (aviary-ensemble is the slug of the article):
http://127.0.0.1:8002/articles/article/aviary-ensemble/
Now I'm making a comment system and the form for writing a comment is on the same page.

The view for creating a new comment I have formalized as follows: if there is no submitted data, then load the page, if there is - then based on this data create a comment and load the page.
def details(request, slug, author=None):

article = models.Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
print(author)
if request.method == 'POST':

    if author is not None:
        user = User.objects.get(username=author)
        print(user.username, type(user))
        comment_author = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        comment = request.POST['comment_area']
        if comment[0] == '@':
            receiver = comment[1:].split(', ')[0]
            comment_text = comment[1:].split(', ')[1]
            models.Comment.objects.create(article=article, author=comment_author, receiver=receiver,
                                          text=comment_text)
        else:
            models.Comment.objects.create(article=article, author=comment_author, text=comment)

        article_comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(article=article)

        context = {
            'article': article,
            'article_comments': article_comments
        }
        return render(request, 'articles/article.html', context=context)
else:
    article.views = article.views + 1

    article_comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(article=article)

    context = {
        'article': article,
        'article_comments': article_comments
    }

    return render(request, 'articles/article.html', context=context)

I set the url itself as follows:
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='articles_catalog'),
path('article/<slug:slug>/<str:author>/', views.details, name='comment_creation'),
path('article/<slug:slug>/', views.details, name='details'),
]

The nuance is that after submitting the form the url changes to
http://127.0.0.1:8002/articles/article/aviary-ensemble/admin/
(admin is the username of the active User who is the author of the comment).
Actually, what I want to achieve: after submitting the form, I would like the url to change to http://127.0.0.1:8002/articles/article/aviary-ensemble/.
i.e. without the name addition.
The method of googling gave the following variant (but it did not work - url doesn't change): request.path_info = '/articles/article/' + str(article.slug) + '/'
I double-checked - both url's refer to the same view.
Could you please tell me if it is possible to formalize this somehow?

You should redirect to details page again once comment it saved.
your url will be updated to http://127.0.0.1:8002/articles/article/aviary-ensemble/
This will make code much simpler and align with Django DRY principle.
import reverse_lazy to use this code
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


def details(request, slug, author=None):

article = models.Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
print(author)
if request.method == 'POST':

    if author is not None:
        user = User.objects.get(username=author)
        print(user.username, type(user))
        comment_author = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        comment = request.POST['comment_area']
        if comment[0] == '@':
            receiver = comment[1:].split(', ')[0]
            comment_text = comment[1:].split(', ')[1]
            models.Comment.objects.create(article=article, author=comment_author, receiver=receiver,
                                        text=comment_text)
        else:
            models.Comment.objects.create(article=article, author=comment_author, text=comment)


        # redirect the page to details again. you can use reverse_lazy for retriving url
        redirect_url = reverse_lazy('details', kwargs={'slug': slug})
        return redirect(redirect_url)
else:
    article.views = article.views + 1

    article_comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(article=article)

    context = {
        'article': article,
        'article_comments': article_comments
    }

    return render(request, 'articles/article.html', context=context)


it worked!!! Thank you so much for your help!

great, kindly accept the answer
